# Symbolic-Link always points to its parent directory

Tags: node.js, file

Placing Symbolic-Links other than the current directory does not work because they always point to their current directory

I'm on Windows 10, what I'm missing?

```
fs.symlink('./testFile', './testDir/testSymLink', function(err){       // creates a symbolic- link in the 'testDir' subfolder relative to the current directory 
    if(err) console.log(err);
});

fs.readlink('./testDir/testSymlink',function(err, links){              // reads the created symbolic link 
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(links);                                                // -> '.\testFile'   (points to the current directory not to the parent directory)
});

fs.readFile('./testDir/testSymlink.txt', function(err, data){          // file doesn't exist
    if(err) console.log(err);                                          // -> ENOENT no such file or directory 
    console.log(data);                                                 // -> undefined 
});
```

The symbolic link is created (we can read it) but points to its current directory `.\testFile` it should point to its parent directory where the reference file is `..\testFile`

Answer (score 0):

the `symlink()` method's 1st argument is the target location used by the created symbolic-link.

It's is important to know that the symbolic-link uses the 1st argument as it was passed! (does not resolve it as absolute path!)

Here is the tricky part, because the above 1st argument is `./testFile` the symbolic-link will use this path to reference the 'testFile' in its own directory (not in the parent directory)

Solutions:

1 : the above code could be fixed like this (the `testSymLink` in the `testDir` directory references the `testFile` in the parent directory)

```
fs.symlink('../testFile', './testDir/testSymLink', function(err){       
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

2 : passing absolute path as 1st argument in the `symlink()` method (this will save you a lot of hassle!)

```
fs.symlink(/* absolute path */, './testDir/testSymLink', function(err){       
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```